# jwt silent login with refresh token (remix and external be)

Tags: jwt, remix.run

I have a go backend with two endpoints:

- /login (expects user credentials) -> (create ACCESS_TOKEN and REFRESH_TOKEN, store both in redis) -> returns ACCESS_TOKEN and REFRESH_TOKEN
- /refresh (expects REFRESH_TOKEN) -> (create NEW_ACCESS_TOKEN and NEW_REFRESH_TOKEN, store both in redis, delete REFRESH_TOKEN) -> return NEW_ACCESS_TOKEN and NEW_REFRESH_TOKEN

As fe I use remix.

Login:

send credentials to remix be (action) -> request /login route with axios -> store ACCESS_TOKEN and the REFRESH_TOKEN in [cookie session](https://remix.run/docs/en/main/utils/sessions#createcookiesessionstorage) -> forward to dashboard

Now I have the ACCESS_TOKEN and the REFRESH_TOKEN in the client in the cookies.

When the ACCESS_TOKEN expires I can use the [interceptors of axios](https://axios-http.com/docs/interceptors) to get a NEW_ACCESS_TOKEN and NEW_REFRESH_TOKEN, found an example e.g. [here](https://dev.to/franciscomendes10866/how-to-use-axios-interceptors-b7d). In this example the mem library is used to not request multiple new NEW_REFRESH_TOKENS at the same time.

**The problem:**

In all this examples it is possible to store the new refresh token directly in the cookies because all of this code is executed on the client. In remix all this code is executed on the be side and I have to propagate back the NEW_REFRESH_TOKEN to the client over the 'set-cookie' header. How is this done properly.

I tried it e.g. like this but it is not working because of some race conditions between multiple actions and loaders as well.

```
export const action = async ({request}: ActionArgs) => {
  const { data, headers } = await DefaultApi.getA(request)
  const { data, headers } = await DefaultApi.getB(request)
  const { data, headers } = await DefaultApi.getC(request)
  console.log(data,headers)

  return json(data, { headers: {'set-cookie': headers || ''} })  
}
```